# How to display the found line at the top of the window in notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++

When I am editing certain files I open them in Notepad++ and search for patterns. The line with the next match then shows up in the middle of the window, or if it was already inside the window it remains where it was (typically in the lower half, if a forward search was done). Then I typically want to edit the next N lines (N between 10 and maybe 35...) from the found one.
It would be very convenient if the line with the match would be at the top of the window (or a specified number of lines offset from top/middle/bottom) so I wouldn't need to scroll down to where I must edit.
Is this feature available already, or is it something that would require a feature request and implementation?

Comment: Currently, I adjust the height of the window so that the last line display the last line of interest within the range for that search match, but not the next line, which may contain another match. Then the next match will get displayed in the middle of the window. If the number of lines of interest change between matches, I need to resize the window accordingly.

Comment: Pressing control plus up or down arrows may be useful, it moves the text up or down, but keeps the cursor in the same place within the text.